# Data Extension data output with Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a two column data extension DE with EMAIL and SENT. I need to output data on an email.

Columns:

**Email** = This is not an email address, it is the name of an email template.

**Sent** = The total of email sent for this Email.

I tried using this code:

`SET @p11 = LookupRowsCS("OFFERS","Email","EML_OFFERS_ONE")`

then to output the value i used `Field(Row(@p11,1),"Sent")`

My existing solution is not dynamic, can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

I just need to be able to output `%%=V(@email)=%%` `%%=V(@sent)=%%` in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's  an example from my blog:  [**AMPScript Lookup Examples**](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)

The third one down is closest to what you're describing.

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[

next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```